# Fileupload don't open on LinkButton click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

i am trying use jquery function to open fileupload control,

code in head section of page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chooseFile() {

       document.getElementById("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").click();
       alert('test');

   }
</script>
```

code in aspx page

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick='chooseFile();' ID="lnkBtnUploadImage" runat="server">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
```

i tried putting alert in function before document.getElementById it shows alert but not opening fileupload. if i put alert after document.getElementById it won't show alert or fileupload

Comment: File inputs are very tight on security. You cannot trigger link clicks on them in most modern browsers.

Comment: i tried  <input type="button" name="Click" onclick='chooseFile();' value="click" /> instead of LinkButton still not able to open fileupload

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
function chooseFile() {
$('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me. is it possible the case of conflict of js?